# Arrow inside a rectangle

Tags: graphics, gui-construction

I would like to create a `Graphics` similar to the top one here: [image]

, but I can obtain only the bottom one.

I use this:

```
Graphics[{
      {Arrow[{{0,-4},{0,5}}]},
      {Red,Thickness[0.03],Arrow[{{0,1},{0,4}}]},
      {Blue,Thickness[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0},{0,-3.5}}]},
      {EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]],White,Rectangle[{-1,-1},{1,1}]}
      }]
```

How can I show the blue line inside the rectangle?

How can I make bigger the top of the arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `White` to:

```
   FaceForm[None]
```

Comment: That works.
Can I do something for the thickness of the extreme of the arrow?

Comment: Use:  `Arrowheads[.1]`

Answer (score 4):

Since the graphics primitives are layered in the order they appear, an alternative approach is to have the `Rectangle` before the `Arrow` primitives. This can be done by using `RotateRight` on the list of graphics primitives:

```
graphics = Graphics[{{Arrow[{{0, -4}, {0, 5}}]}, 
    {Red, Thickness[0.03], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {0, 4}}]},
    {Blue, Thickness[0.03], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, -3.5}}]}, 
    {EdgeForm[Directive[Thick]], White, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}}];

MapAt[{Arrowheads[.2], RotateRight@#} &, graphics, {1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]